# Синхронизация доступа к ArrayList

Tags: многопоточность, java, коллекции

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос:

1. В javadoc написано, что для `thread-safe` доступа к `ArrayListу` его нужно декорировать через `Collections.synchronizeList`. Я так понял, что этот метод просто возвращает `list` методы которого `synchronized`, это так?
2. Из того же javadoc:

   ```
   List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
   synchronized(list) {
     Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
     while (i.hasNext())
       foo(i.next());
   }
   ```

> It is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned list when iterating over it: ...

Зачем в этом случае вручную синхронизировать через `synchronized(list)`? Или это нужно делать, только когда работаешь с итераторами, и не обязательно, если обращаешься к листу через `get()`, `add()`, `set()`?
Спасибо.

Comment: я задам встречный вопрос: а зачем в многопоточной программе использовать несинхронизированные классы вместо синхронизированых и использовать приемы называющиеся "привинчиванием костылей"?

Vector ?  
SynchronizedList ?

Comment: @jmu, с `Vector` поосторожнее. Одно его упоминание вызывает гнев богов :) Кстати, декоратор сам по себе не является костылём и в некоторых случаях такой подход может быть полезен. Но только в некоторых.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Ну так посмотрите, что делает  Collections.synchronizedList.. в IDE контрол-клик и читайте, что написано. Но вообще, вы обнаружите, что да, там каждый метод synchronized.
2. Соответственно, этот факт и является причиной того, что есть необходимость синхронизоваться отдельно. Всё дело в том, что итератор сломается, если кто-то выполнит модификауцию списка **между** вызовами next(). Чтобы этого избежать и приходится делать более крупный блок synchronized.
3. И да, нарушение внутреннего состояния списка внутри методов set никто не отменял: одновременный вызов метода set из разных поток с высокой вероятностью разрушит список. Поэтому, надо делать synchronizedList. Ну или можно просто руками везде синхронизовать, а не оборачивать. Лично я обычно так и делаю и редко пользуюсь этим декоратором. Он обычно полезен, если вы отдаёте список куда-то наружу, чего я стараюсь всеми правдами и неправдами избежать.

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, это нужно для того, чтобы пока работает итератор (обладает объектом блокировки данного листа), никто больше не мог вызвать `set() add()`, для вызова которых нужен тот же самый объект блокировки? Так?

Comment: Да, именно для этого.

Comment: И да, нарушение внутреннего состояния списка внутри методов set никто не отменял: >> в javadoc написано что set - не структурная операция и её можно не синхронизировать. Так как поступать в случае с set() ?

Comment: Где это вы там нашли такое? Почитайте исодник метода set для ArrayList. Очевидно, что он не потокобезопасен. Или вы имеете в виду synchronizedList?

Comment: @Vladimir, лучше весь локинг (синхронизацию) делайте сами. Разбираться потом будет проще.

Comment: Я понимаю, я так, для себя - чтоб разобраться. Вот цитата из javadoc для ArrayList - Note that this implementation is not synchronized.  If multiple threads access an ArrayList instance concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the list structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more elements, or explicitly resizes the backing array; merely setting the value of an element is not a structural modification.)

Comment: Я думаю это неточность. Если вызвать set в тот момент, как кто-то делает, например, trim, то set потеряется. Т.е. set можно комбинировать, вероятно, только с другим set. Нельзя даже комбинировать set и get на самом деле.